# (Pi 3B) CPU Usage turn low while using video record and servo

Tags: streaming-video, cpu

I am doing a project is using Robot arm to classify package has QR code. Webcam starts streaming and if it scans correct those QR which I set in Python code, the Robot arm picks and places it to other place,those process makes Pi's CPU turns to 1-3% and get frame delay in quite time. Anyone know about this problem please help me. I am apprieciate.

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand your post. I read that low CPU load is a problem, but that's actually no problem at all! Take your time to describe what is **not** working, what behaviour you expect and what symptoms you see.